# Blue-green deployment on Web Service with WebSocket Implementation on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, devops

I'm currently looking to implement Web sockets for a couple of Web services. But was wondering how this stateful http connections will impact Blue-green deployments & auto-scaling on AWS.

Was googling around but haven't came across anything. Would appreciate any advice / inputs.

Answer (score 4):

Use connection draining (sending all new requests to your desired environment - green for example) and giving time for blue clients to fall off.

You can set the max-lifetime of your websocket (connection draining period should be longer than max if that kind of reliability is needed)

Otherwise would just handle client side. If websocket drops initiate new connection through your AWS ELB to a healthy server. Do not keep any state on your ephemeral ELB backends. This also would also work when scaling down on AWS.

Comment: "connection draining period can longer than max if that kind of reliability is needed" ... I would assume that kind of reliability is always needed.